# Ingest Firebase Dynamic Links Metrics

Tags: python, firebase

I'm looking for a way to ingest/crawl firebase dynamic links metrics.

[image]

[image]

I found that the firebase console has internal api endpoint `getDurableLinks` that returns the data, but I can use it in my scripted python code unless I got long-lasting cookie code to ingest it daily.

[image]

Anyone know the workaround for this problem? like automatically saves cookie code to local disk whenever I logged to firebase.

UPDATE:
I know that there is a documentation about how to get analytic `https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics` but I need the historical dates for each days metric.